# Getting Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ProjectName.DTOs.ProjectDTO] instead of actual Data

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on my .NET MVC Core project. I am trying to get the project name by joining two tables using LINQ in my Controller.
My Controller code:

```
public IActionResult Projects()
{
    var projectName = from p in _context.Tbl_Projects
                      join d in _context.Tbl_MyOfficeDocumets on p.Id equals d.Project_ID
                      select new ProjectDTO { ProjectName = p.ProjectName };

    ProjectDTO proj = new ProjectDTO { ProjectName = projectName; }

    return View(proj);
}
```

And Razor view page:

```
<table>

<tr>
   <td>Your Projects</td>
   <td>Description</td>
   <td>Created On</td>
</tr>

@foreach(var item in Model.listOfProjects)
<tr>
   <td>@Model.ProjectName</td>  <-- Here I am getting that unusual response
   <td>@item.Description</td>
   <td>@item.CreatedOn</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

The `@Model.ProjectName` shows:

> Getting Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ProjectName.DTOs.ProjectDTO]

Am I missing something?

Comment: you bind ProjectDTO to string ProjectName for 2nd time. I dont understand why you still bind again when you have ProjectDTO already.

Comment: You can use like this `ProjectDTO proj = new ProjectDTO { ProjectName = projectName.ProjectName; }`

Answer (score 0):

You have created query and assigned it to DTO, which is wrong.

```
public IActionResult Projects()
{
    var query = from p in _context.Tbl_Projects
                join d in _context.Tbl_MyOfficeDocumets on p.Id equals d.Project_ID
                select new ProjectDTO { ProjectName = p.ProjectName };
  
    return View(query);
}
```